# How to set VirtualBox machine name to be the same as the hostname in multi-machine Vagrantfile?

Tags: ruby, ansible, vagrant, vagrantfile

The following `Vagrantfile` configuration won't work as the next VM gets the same name as previous one. (BTW, not 100% sure, but I think this used to work in previous Vagrant versions).

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|

  config.vm.define "xfcevm" do |xfcevm|
    xfcevm.vm.box = "generic/ubuntu1904"
    xfcevm.vm.hostname = "xfcevm"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "xfcevm"
    end
  end

  config.vm.define "gnomevm" do |gnomevm|
    gnomevm.vm.box = "generic/fedora30"
    gnomevm.vm.hostname = "gnomevm"
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "gnomevm"
    end
  end

  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    # vb.name = config.vm.hostname
    vb.gui = true
    vb.memory = "3072"
    vb.cpus = 1
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--vram", "32"]
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible" do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
    ansible.playbook = "setup.yml"
  end

  config.vm.provision "ansible", run: 'always' do |ansible|
    ansible.verbose = "v"
    ansible.compatibility_mode = "2.0"
    ansible.playbook = "tests.yml"
  end

end
```

In the line `# vb.name = config.vm.hostname`, the assignment returns an object (it is printed with `puts` as `#<Object:0x0000000001c191d8>`) and I'm not familiar with Ruby and Vagrant enough to get a string attribute from it if that's even possible from that object.

P.S. a workaround (an alternative question to this one) would be to get the running VirtualBox machine name from Ansible playbook, as the goal has been calling `VBoxManage` on that virtual machine as `local_action` from inside the Ansible playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the virtualbox provider on the `config` global object.

```
    # Wrong for multivm
    # This sets a default name for all vms
    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "gnomevm"
    end
```

Simply call this on the current vm you are defining (example for `gnomevm`)

```
    # Correct
    # This sets the specific name for this vm only
    gnomevm.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.name = "gnomevm"
    end
```

Comment: Simple as that! :) Thank you!